# Why web services remains an integrated part in .net 4.0

Tags: wcf

Why 'web services' concept has not been removed from VS 2010 becoz WCF services provides almost all features which 'web services' does. Is there anything available in web services which can not be implemented by WCF service or is just becoz of backward compatibility?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ,

Thanx

Comment: Not **ALL** the web services out there that you could connect to are .NET and thus WCF .... I'm pretty sure a large group of people would get pretty angry if Microsoft removed the ability to connect to any kind of third-party web service out there. Yes it's still there for backward compatibility.

Comment: you're confused. What you call "Web Services" are "ASMX Web Services", and they are now considered to be a legacy technology. WCF implements web services, plus much more.

Answer (score 3):

Because .NET is downwards compatible to any version >= .NET 2. Removing anything from .NET that is part of a an earlier release would destroy downward compatibility.
Remember: .NET 3 is a superset of .NET 2, .NET 3.5 is a superset of .NET 3 and so on...

Comment: yaa downward compatibility may be the reason behind that. As far as i know webservices does support session management .Does 'WCF Services' support session?????

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, some people (not me) at my company actually *prefer* web services or WCF services because adding them makes less changes to the config file.  You do have to admit that WCF services take considerably more setup than web services.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely because SOAP remains a significant interop mechanism between .NET and Java systems (among others). *And* removing web services would make the tons of code that has already been written to do said interop stop functioning. Web services aren't going anywhere.

Comment: @seand as are .NET web services. OP is referring to two MS-specific technologies and asking why the newer has not supplanted the older.

Comment: @seand: That doesn't matter. WCF supports all major web service standards. A client or server doesn't care about the technology which is used on the other side.

Comment: I don't have hands on WCF experience myself but I believe it's an abstraction that in turn uses standard services down below (web services, plain tcp sockets etc).  Those are standard services avail on lots of platforms, but the WCF abstraction itself is M$ specific.

Comment: @seand: WCF is a MS implementation - but it's the technology that implements **the most** WS-* specs of all technologies out there today. It's **extremely** interoperable - don't insinuate it's not just because it's Microsoft that built it....

Comment: @seand I dont know if I get your point. WCF is obviously a Microsoft specific technology but if you implement a web service or a client and specify that it should provide/consume data in form of standard X, Y or Z you don't have to care about the technology which is used on the other end. For example you could create a service which provides data as JSON and cosume this data querying mydomain.example/mysupercoolservice.svc with a client written in Java. WCF supports many protocols, formats and transports. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation